# Enabling logging/debugging in Azure worker role to azure storage

Tags: visual-studio, azure-worker-roles, azure-diagnostics, azure-deployment

I have a .net project that I am trying to deploy as a worker role in Azure. I am able to publish the file directly from Visual Studio but then when the worker role runs I am getting a uncaught exception. I am attempting to enable logging to azure storage from the worker role so I can get more information on the exception but I am running into issues getting MIT configured.  Can anyone provide assistance on the best way to enable this logging?

Comment: You should following the MSDN guide here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn186185.aspx. Note that it's not real-time - output is batched and appears periodically.  Depending on where the exception occurs you may not see anything.  For troubleshooting purposes you can enable RDP and remote into your server and look at the event logs if you want: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mast/archive/2013/07/20/configure-remote-desktop-via-management-portal-for-windows-azure-cloud-services.aspx

Comment: Thanks!  I will go through this now. Using Remote Desktop might be the easiest for now and then get the logging to the storage account setup for long term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not a massive fan of the recommended Azure Worker Role logging process, namely using the Trace.WriteLine() method as I don’t feel as though it provides sufficient flexibility for my logging needs and I think it looks crap when my code is liberally scattered with Trace.WriteLine() statements, code is art and all that. I also don't like that Trace statements aren't always logged and can be 'lost' if the Worker Role hiccups or generally goes astray.

I therefore came up with an approach that writes log files to local storage via NLog, which are then flushed to Azure Storage on a schedule. Works like a charm.

I've got it documented over in the blog post at: https://modhul.wordpress.com/2014/10/28/capturing-custom-logs-from-azure-worker-roles-using-azure-diagnostics/

If I want to watch my log files in real-time (rather than waiting for them to be flushed to Azure Storage), I RDP into the Worker Role instance and fire-up  a copy of BareTail (http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/) which is a great way of watching log files in real-time, it also lets you add colour-coding for errors, info, warnings etc.

Comment: This is interesting.  I will pass this along to our developers.  So far I have just been using RDP to grab any exceptions via the Azure section in Event Viewer.  Definitely not a good solution.

Comment: Hi @k2737 - I've added some detail to my answer about monitoring log files over RDP.

Comment: @NickHeppleston it looks like the link to your blog post is broken -- any chance you can update your answer to contain the relevant information?

Comment: Any chance you still have an example somewhere? You blog link is busted.

Comment: Link only answer, and link is broken.