# can nlog configuration be set within azure worker role cloudconfiguration files

Tags: azure, nlog, azure-worker-roles

I'm using nlog with an azure worker role.  I know that I can include an nlog.config file within the workerrole project.

I'm wondering if there is someway to include that configuration within the cloudconfiguration files for the worker role?

Or am I stuck with configuring nlog programmatically based on the contents of the cloudconfig?

Comment: What's the goal? To control nlog's parameters from within the configuration and within the portal? Or to have different settings for different environments (e.g., cloud vs local)?

Comment: my guess would be to configure nlog setting from the portal - say I see issues with the deployment and I want to change the severity level for some time to inspect the logs, then change it back ...

Answer (score 3):

I answered a similar question over at [Enabling logging/debugging in Azure worker role to azure storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28423610/enabling-logging-debugging-in-azure-worker-role-to-azure-storage/28466184#28466184).

To cut a long story short, you can specify the NLog configuration in the Worker Role App.config file, rather than the Service Definition file; but there are a lot more hoops to jump through to get NLog working correctly with an Azure Worker Role which I document in the blog post at https://modhul.wordpress.com/2014/10/28/capturing-custom-logs-from-azure-worker-roles-using-azure-diagnostics/